# socket.recv() in a Django application is not working properly

Tags: python, django, sockets

As stated in the subject, socket.recv() in python, used in a django application is not working as expected. When I do the following commands in IDLE/ipython prompt, all data is received from the server:

```
import socket
s = socket.socket()
s.connect((host,port))
s.setblocking(0)
s.send("<some commands">)
data = ""
while True:
    try:
        new=s.recv(256)
        if not new: break
        data+=new
    except:
        break
```

After breaking from the while loop, data variable has all the received data.
Now when I put this into the views.py of my Django application like this:

```
s = _sendQuery(host, port)
data = s._receiveAll(s)

def _sendQuery(host, port):
    sock = None
    try:
        sock = socket.socket()
        sock.connect((host, port))
        sock.setblocking(0)
        sock.send("<some commands>")
    finally:
        return sock

def _receiveAll(sock):
    data = ""
    while True:
        try:
            temp = sock.recv(256)
            if not temp: break
            data+=temp
        except Exception, ex:
            data+=ex
    return data.strip()
```

Now when I call the app via browser, it returns the exception message:

> [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable

which tells me that during the first call to sock.recv(256), it has encountered an exception already (related to the sock.setblocking(0)), which is why the value of the variable data is the exception message only.

Anyone has an idea how to fix this? I'm quite stuck here. 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this, and I'm sharing it in case someone will find it useful. In the _receiveAll function, I modified this code from this:

```
if not temp: break
```

to this:

```
if len(temp) < 256:
    data+=temp
    break
```

I also removed the s.setblocking(0).

Hope this helps.